# Ajax Response as HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, response

When the submit button is clicked on `page1.php` the response is printed as HTML format for a moment but it gets automatically deleted.

I want to display the response of `page2.php` in *page1* in the `id="output"` element.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the content of `page1.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func(tosearch) {
        alert("search");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'page2.php',
            data: {
                'tosearch' : tosearch
            },
            success: function(result) {
                print(result);
            }
        });
    }

    function print(result) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=result;
    }
</script>

<form method="post" action="page1.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="func()">
</form>
<p id="output">table here!!</p>
```

Content of `page2.php`

```
<?php echo "<table align='center'>"
    ."<tr>"
    ."<td>"."Mr XYZ"."</td>"
    ."<td>"."MALE"."</td>"
    ."<td>"."987558745"."</td>"
    ."<td>"."xyz@gmail.com"."</td>"
    ."</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: You can try removing the method and action attribute in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response isn't being deleted, the page is refreshing.  Since you don't want the page to refresh at all, you don't really need that `form` element.  Just remove the `form` and make the `input` a plain `button` to keep the markup simple:

```
<script>
    // your JavaScript
</script>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."><br><br>
<button onclick="func()">    
<p id="output">table here!!</p>
```

Comment: Or just add `event.preventDefault();` into the `func()`

Comment: @NewToJS: True, but if the event should *always* be prevented and the form should *never* be used as a form then there's really no need to have any of it in the first place.  Better to remove unneeded things than to write more code just to ignore/prevent unneeded things.

Comment: Very true but some people like to target the form to `serialize` the data. For *Aman Tiwari* use your answer is better but for others that might read this question seeking help I thought I would place a comment as it might help others.

Comment: `tosearch` is not defined

Comment: @charlietfl that's because nothing is being passed in the function call. `onclick="func()"`

Comment: @NewToJS I realize that...answer doesn't cover it is my point

Comment: @charlietfl: It doesn't seem to need to be defined, but you're right I did miss it in the answer code.  Corrected.  Looking at it now, I suspect the OP will eventually want to pass that value to the server after correcting the current roadblock.

Comment: @David ah yeah, good point! :p I did get that user mixed up with the OP.